# Generate pretty image of tree/graph

Tags: image, tree, graph, graphviz

I want to generate a pretty image of my tree/graph data. I had a look at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php), but the renderings are not great. Do you know of a solution that will produce pretty images and run on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/gallery.html) is an amazing network graph library, in which you can generate images of graphs and trees.

I would take another look at Graphviz, from my limited experience, the output by default is not all that pretty, but, with a little work, you can [style it](http://www.hokstad.com/making-graphviz-output-pretty-with-xsl.html) to look much better.

Another option is [Gephi](http://gephi.org/)--I've never used it, but it does run on Linux.